# delete everything before last comma

Tags: java, regex

I want to delete everything before the last tab (or comma).

For example, in this sentence:

> Hoe treedt een                       gevestigd instituut als het Nederlands                         Openluchtmuseum, alom geassocieerd met                       ambacht en traditie, buiten zijn grenzen op zoek                       naar vernieuwing?

should be

> naar vernieuwing?
>
> Ik heb ruim 6 weken geleden een boek besteld en ik wacht nog steeds,enig idee hoe lang dit wachten nog gaat duren?

should be

> enig idee hoe lang dit wachten nog gaat duren?

I tried this,

"^(.*\t+)+" but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
^.*?([^\t,]*)$
```

and replace with `$1`

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30d4f)

Answer (score 5):

Regular Expressions are the wrong tool for this job.

Just use `lastIndexOf()` to find the last `,` and/or `\t` and then use `substring()` to lop off what you want to keep.

Either way, writing this out using the proper Java idioms, will be more self documenting and more maintainable in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking of it as deleting the part before the last comma, you can think of it as extracting the part after the last comma. This can be achieved with the following regex:

```
(?:[,\t]|^)([^,\t]*)$
```

Explanation:

- `(?:[,\t]|^)` either matches a `,`, a tab or the start of the string. (Doesn't capture.)
- `([^,\t]*)` captures any symbol following it that isn't a `,` or tab.
- `$` anchors it to the end of a string.

As a whole this should do the job.

Answer (score -1):

```
String s1 = "asdfasdadfsdf,asdfasd,fasd,fasd,fasdf";

            s1.lastIndexOf(",");
            System.out.println(s1.substring(s1.lastIndexOf(",")+1,s1.length()));
```